# What to do with an incomplete answer that the OP posted on another question where it's a complete answer and the OP is inactive?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted a question like 1.5 years ago: [The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAcces.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946467/the-type-initializer-for-oracle-dataacces-client-oracleconnection-threw-an-exc) where I got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946467/the-type-initializer-for-oracle-dataacces-client-oracleconnection-threw-an-exc/29547215#29547215) and he forgot to put code where he wanted to put code. Then I checked the users profile and saw that he had 1 more post which was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226188/c-sharp-error-the-type-initializer-for-threw-an-exception/29547122#29547122) to a **somewhat** same question but that answer was complete at that question(so with code).

What should I do with the answer on my question?

Edit it to the same answer as the one he posted on the other question? (OP did intend to have both answers to be exactly the same)

Flag it since it's not an answer right now?

**NOTE:**

The answer(s) on both questions are not useful in this case.(But lets say it would be for people in the future)

Comment: Technically he didn't add the code, blackbishop edited it in: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29547122/revisions

Comment: @JamieBarker Aha thanks. The question still remains though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit it. The only reason the code wasn't displayed was because it was put within angle brackets and he hadn't formatted it for code.

It's like if I put a random word here in angle brackets, like , you can't see the amusing word I've written because it thinks it's HTML

If you edit my answer here, you would see I wrote:

> testicles

Oh and I edited his other answer on your question for good measure too :).

Comment: Without editting I can see what you wrote

Comment: Out of interest, how?

Comment: I just hover over it? Am I missing something? :P

Comment: In public, I rarely admit to hovering over testicles.

Comment: @Loko Yes you are. Press edit, read the second paragraph and you'll see what I mean ;). I only put the spoiler in there for lazy people who don't want to click edit, and for a bit of crude fun.

Comment: I cant click edit. `suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.`

Comment: @Loko Oh for goodness sake, go and get another 38 rep so you can ;P

Comment: @JamieBarker Hahaha this is the goofiest conversation in comments I've ever seen.  The random hovering over testicles part helps as well.

Comment: @BillWoodger do you have a specialized drone for the purpose?

Comment: @bmargulies well, if I did I'd not admit to it.